# UI5 get Model in OPA test

Tags: integration-testing, sapui5

I am trying to get values from a JSON model in my Journey file. In the page it's no Problem to get the values, because I can easily get my view.

The problem is, I don't know how to return values from an OPA test back to the Journey file.

Part of the Journey:

```
opaTest("Should Navigate to all Workflows and Navigate Home", function(Given, When, Then) {
    // Arrangements starting the app in Frame
    Given.iStartMyApp();

    //should return the array length of the model
    var iLength = When.onTheLayerPage.getNumberOfLayers();

    for (var iPosition = 0; iPosition < iLength; iPosition++) {
        When.onTheLayerPage.iSelectListItemAtPosition(iPosition);
        var iChildLength = When.onTheLayerPage.getNumberOfWorkflows(iPosition);
        for (var iChildPosition = 0; iChildPosition < iChildLength; iChildPosition++) {
            When.onTheLayerPage.iSelectChildListItemAtPosition(iPosition, iChildPosition);
            Then.onTheWorkflowPage.iShouldSeeThePage();
            When.onTheAppPage.iPressHomeButton();
            Then.onTheLayerPage.iShouldSeeThePage();
        }
    }
```

Part of the page:

```
getNumberOfLayers: function() {
    this.waitFor({
        id: sPageId,
        viewName: sViewName,
        actions: function(oPage) {
            var iLenght = oPage.getModel("out").getProperty("/r/data/layers").length;
            return iLenght;
        }
    });
},
```

Seems the waitFor on the page is triggered when I am already in the for loop (maybe based on Promise), so `iLenght` is undefined.

Looking for a way to return the var before the loop is starting.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution to your issue but how you'd go about implementing it specifically depends on how you create the model in your app.

When writing OPA tests, you can prepare specific objects or data for later use in the "setup" method of the "module" object and destroy them in the "teardown" method. So in your journey file you can use something like this to create a variable and assign it to the test page object:

```js
 module("Test page model", {
  setup: function() {
   this.iLength = models.createModel().getProperty("/r/data/layers").length;
  },
  teardown: function() {
   this.iLength = null;
  }
 });
```

Then in your actual opa test you can access the variable:

```js
opaTest("Should Navigate to all Workflows and Navigate Home", function(Given, When, Then) {
    // Arrangements starting the app in Frame
    Given.iStartMyApp();

    //should return the array length of the model
    //var iLength = When.onTheLayerPage.getNumberOfLayers(); <- don't need this line

    for (var iPosition = 0; iPosition < this.iLength; iPosition++) { // Access the previously created variable here
        When.onTheLayerPage.iSelectListItemAtPosition(iPosition);
        var iChildLength = When.onTheLayerPage.getNumberOfWorkflows(iPosition);
    for (var iChildPosition = 0; iChildPosition < iChildLength; iChildPosition++) {
        When.onTheLayerPage.iSelectChildListItemAtPosition(iPosition, iChildPosition);
        Then.onTheWorkflowPage.iShouldSeeThePage();
        When.onTheAppPage.iPressHomeButton();
        Then.onTheLayerPage.iShouldSeeThePage();
    }
}
```

The code in the models.js file to create the model is:

```js
  createModel: function() {
   var oTestModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
     "r": {
      "data": {
       "layers": [
        {"dummy": 1},
        {"dummy": 2},
        {"dummy": 3}
        ]
      }
     }
    });
   return oTestModel;
  }
```

If you don't create your model in a method in a separate file, you'll need to work out a way of instantiating it in the "setup" method but I think the principle will be the same. That method is executed each time a new opaTest is started but there might be some alternative methods you can dig out of the source code or find in some documentation that is only called once. I don't have time right now but holler if you can't and I can take a look later. Hope it helps.